# How to specify my own ios app as Suggested app on itunes?

Tags: ios, ios8, ibeacon

I have developed an app in iOS which plays around iBeacon technology. 
However i want my app to be shown as suggested app if user is nearby to any location. I read that for app having iBeacon implementation, the device must have app installed so that it would be displayed at left bottom corner in iOS8 as soon as beacon is detected.

But if user has not installed my app and if he comes near to specific location, i want my app to be suggested on left bottom corner.

How can it be achieved ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. iOS listens to beacons and only reasons for which it knows to listen for.

Since there can be unlimited number a beacons to listen to the device is restricted to only listen to those beacons that apps have requested it to listen for. And this is what makes you app appear in the lower left corner in the lock screen.

Comment: Ok. But if i want suggest my app to user who is near to any location, how can it be achieved? Can i do it? if yes what steps i need to follow to make my app as suggested app on store ?

Comment: You can't, place a poster at the location telling the people to download your app is your only option. Just like the firs part of my answer "This is not possible" !!!!